# How to get months return with While loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am learning JS and am having trouble figuring this out. I would like to ask if any of you can spot my error. I would like to use a while loop to return the names of all of the months january through december without using an array, is this possible? Thank you.

```
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = getMonth(11);   
};

for(var month=0; month < 11; month++)

function getMonth(month) {
    var monthName;
    if (month == 11) {
         monthName = "December";
     }
     return monthName;
 }

 function getMonth()
{
var x="",month=0;
while (month<11)
  {
  x=x + month + "<br>";
  i++;
  }
document.getElementById("months").innerHTML=x;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/priswiz/xuJRc/

Comment: what do you have against arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without an array:

```
function getMonth(month) {
  switch(month){
     case 0: return "January";
     case 1: return "February"; 
     //...
     case 11: return "December";
     default: return "Not a valid Month";
   }
 }
```

But thats a painful way to do it.

With array:

```
function getMonth(month){
  var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
  return monthNames[month];
}
```

I have no idea what you'd want to do with a while loop without an array.  What would you be iterating over?

Comment: While loops just iterate while some condition is met. The condition might be whether a counter is less than some value, or some other calculation or logic. So while a very common use is for iterating over array indexes, there are many other uses too.

Comment: @RobG  I'm aware that you can use it for other things.  But what would you use it for to get the month from a number?  Thats the use case, and I can't see a reason to use a while loop for this problem without an array, unless you're turning it into a Rube-Goldberg algorithm